# `HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException` when sending multipart POST request from Java client, but works in Postman

Tags: spring-boot, multipartform-data

I'm trying to send a multipart POST request from a Java client to a Spring Boot endpoint, but I'm encountering an `HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException` error. Strangely, the same request works perfectly fine when I send it through Postman. I've spent some time debugging and comparing the requests, but I can't seem to figure out what's causing the issue. Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.
The Java client is a project we use to execute cucumber test files and I am writing functional tests for an endpoint that has a file to be uploaded and a JSON object to be sent as multipart request parts.

**Details:**
-Main Project
- Spring Boot version: 3.1.0
- Java version: 17

- Qa Test project

  - Spring Boot version: 3.1.0
  - Java version: 1.8

**Code Sample - Java Client:**

```java
 public boolean makePostRequest(final String endpoint) {

        final HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().setDefaultCookieStore(getRest().getRequestCookies()).build();
        final HttpPost conn = getRestUtil().setUpPostConnection(endpoint);

        // File Upload
        if (Objects.nonNull(getFilePathForPost())) {

            final MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
            builder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

            final File file = new File(getFilePathForPost());
            final FileBody fb = new FileBody(file);
            builder.addPart(getFileParamName(), fb);

            try {

                final String[] lines = getRequestPayload().split("\n");

                for (final String line : lines) {

                    builder.addTextBody(line.split("=")[0], line.split("=")[1], ContentType.parse(multipartRequestPayloadType));
                }

            } catch (final NullPointerException ignored) {
                // A Post request with no payload will be done
            }

            final String boundary = "---------------" + UUID.randomUUID().toString();
            builder.setBoundary(boundary);
            conn.setHeader(CONTENT_TYPE_HEADER, ContentType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA.getMimeType() + ";boundary=" + boundary);
            builder.setContentType(ContentType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);

            conn.setEntity(builder.build());
            conn.getRequestLine();
            setFilePathForPost(null);

        } else if (Objects.nonNull(getRequestPayload())) {

            conn.setHeader(CHARSET_TYPE_HEADER, CHARSET_TYPE_UTF_8);
            conn.setHeader(CONTENT_TYPE_HEADER, getRequestPayloadType());
            conn.setEntity(new StringEntity(getRequestPayload(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        }

    }
```

**Code Sample - Spring Boot Controller:**

```java
@PostMapping(path = "/partners/{partnerSid}/invoices/{invoiceSid}/partner-actions", consumes = {MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE})
public InvoiceApprovalResponse approveInvoice(@PathVariable final UUID partnerSid,
                                              @PathVariable final UUID invoiceSid,
                                              @Valid @RequestPart("data") final InvoiceApprovalRequest request,
                                              @RequestPart("file") final MultipartFile partnerInvoice) {
    // ... controller logic ...
}
```

**Error Message:**

```
org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content-Type 'application/octet-stream' is not supported
```

**Screenshot from Debugger:**
[image: Screenshot from debugger, after request has parts have been created]

**Observations:**

- I've confirmed that I'm setting the `Content-Type` header to `multipart/form-data` in the Java client.
- I'm using the correct part names (`data` and `file`) in the multipart request.
- The server-side controller method is properly annotated to handle `consumes = {MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE}`.
- The request works as expected when sent from Postman, which makes me believe there might be some subtle difference between the two requests.

**Steps I've Taken:**

- I've added a debugger to the client side and verified that that the constructed request is correct.
- I have made an identical request through curl and postman that both get a 200 reponse.

**Question:**

- What could be causing the `HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException` when sending a multipart POST request from my Java client, even though the same request works flawlessly in Postman?
- Are there any differences in how Apache HttpClient constructs the request compared to Postman's request?
- Are there any additional headers or configurations I should be aware of when sending multipart requests from Java using Apache HttpClient?
- Is there a way to further inspect the raw request being sent from the Java client to identify any differences compared to the working Postman request?

Any insights or suggestions to help troubleshoot and resolve this issue would be highly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Comment: That the server complains your client is sending content with the `Content-Type: application/octet-stream` header means that your code most likely does not work in the way you think it does. And the code you included does not look complete so I can not point out where you are wrong. Do follow this guide and ask again: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example